# Invalid template resource property "Tags"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

For the below cloudformation template:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Some Stack",
    "Parameters":{
        "VpcId":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "The target VPC Id"
        },
        "SubnetId":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
            "Description": "The target subnet Id"
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "The key pair that is allowed SSH access"
        }
    },
    "Resources":{
        "EcsCluster":{
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
            "Tags": [ 
                        {
                            "Key": "Name",
                            "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }, "-ecs-cluster" ] ] }     
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "workenv",
                            "Value": "dev"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "abc",
                            "Value": "some_value"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "function",
                            "Value": "someapp"
                        },
                        {
                            "Key": "owner",
                            "Value": "email@abc.com"
                        }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Outputs":{
        "ElbDomainName":{
            "Description": "Public DNS name of Elastic Load Balancer",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "ElasticLoadBalancer",
                    "DNSName"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Below is the error:

```
   Invalid template resource property 'Tags'
```

Am following the below documentation to add tags:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html

---

Why CloudFormation service does not accept `Tags` defined on every resource? something to do with indentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the `Tags` are not defined correctly for `EcsCluster` resource. The `Tags` property should be defined inside the `Properties` section as how you defined `Tags` for other resources.

```
"EcsCluster": {
  "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
  "Properties": {
    "Tags": []
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does `AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile` support `Tags`?

Answer (score 1):

Not all resource types support tags. Check the documentation for each resource type.

Comment: `AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile` does not support `Tags` property, but after removing it, I still see the error. Query edited accordngly

Comment: I would recommend using a linter, like `cfn-lint`. It does a good job of telling you what is wrong.

Comment: cfn-lint  says `Template valid!`, but still AWS console gives an error.

Comment: In that case there is either a bug in cfn-lint (more likely) or a bug in CloudFormation. I would contact support.

Comment: @overexchange you've installed a different `cfn-lint` from `npm`:
https://github.com/martysweet/cfn-lint/blob/50b94c52cb6aa4f51f4809d3cdd6a291aa21d670/src/index.ts#L168

Comment: @overexchange Try installing `cfn-lint` from `pip`: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/